# CSS not Recognizing input box?

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cant get CSS to work with my form? I have tried just about everything and I cant seem to find the issue? What am I doing wrong?

My HTML Structure

```
        <div class="login-container">
            <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="email" />
                <br /><br />
                <label for="pword">Password:</label>
                <input type="text" name="pword" id="pword" />
              </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

My CSS Structure

```
.login-container fieldset {
    padding: 1em;
}
.login-container label {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    padding-top:0.2em;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.input {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: I copied your code to a dabblet. http://dabblet.com/gist/4297057. What doesn't work? Which browser are you testing on? The .input works on the first input field, since it has a class of input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the . in front of your `input` selector.

```
input {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

See also:  [CSS element selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp) vs. [CSS .class selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Comment: Must be caching your CSS make sure to refresh your cache (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: I don't think that's what the questioner is asking about though. He wants for it to be a class.

Comment: I figured out the issue.. I had another css file linked to this document that was conflicting

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine, please see jsfiddle.net/4FCgc/

What is not working? Maybe it is your web browser's cache... But I doubt that.